# Oozie Jobs NOT Running - Getting SUSPENDED

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am running Hadoop with Oozie in pseudo-mode ( I am not using any distribution of hadoop per say by CDH or Hortonworks etc.,). I have having the following configuration while running - **Fedora 22 VM running on VirtualBox, RAM allocated 4GB, Hadoop 2.7, Oozie 4.2**

After I submit the **example Mapreduce job for OOZIE** it gets **SUSPENDED** with the Job error below,

```
2015-10-29 15:44:59,048  WARN ActionStartXCommand:523 - SERVER[hadoop] USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000000-151029154441128-OOZIE-VB-W] ACTION[0000000-151029154441128-OOZIE-VB-W@mr-node] Error starting action [mr-node]. ErrorType [TRANSIENT], ErrorCode [JA009], Message [JA009: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidResourceRequestException: Invalid resource request, requested memory < 0, or requested memory > max configured, requestedMemory=2048, maxMemory=1024
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerUtils.validateResourceRequest(SchedulerUtils.java:204)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.validateAndCreateResourceRequest(RMAppManager.java:385)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.createAndPopulateNewRMApp(RMAppManager.java:328)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.submitApplication(RMAppManager.java:281)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ClientRMService.submitApplication(ClientRMService.java:580)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.submitApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:218)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationClientProtocol$ApplicationClientProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationClientProtocol.java:419)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at     org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: JA009: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidResourceRequestException: Invalid resource request, requested memory < 0, or requested memory > max configured, requestedMemory=2048, maxMemory=1024
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerUtils.validateResourceRequest(SchedulerUtils.java:204)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.validateAndCreateResourceRequest(RMAppManager.java:385)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.createAndPopulateNewRMApp(RMAppManager.java:328)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.submitApplication(RMAppManager.java:281)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ClientRMService.submitApplication(ClientRMService.java:580)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.submitApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:218)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationClientProtocol$ApplicationClientProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationClientProtocol.java:419)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)

at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertExceptionHelper(ActionExecutor.java:456)
at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertException(ActionExecutor.java:440)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:1132)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:1286)
at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:250)
at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:64)
at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:286)
at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:321)
at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:250)
at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I think this is something got to do with the Memory allocations to the MapReduce jobs , but I am not able to figure out the exact math behind this. Help on this is much appreciated.

**mapred-site.xml**

```
  <property>
      <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
      <value>yarn</value>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
      <value>512</value>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
      <value>512</value>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
      <value>http://localhost:50031</value>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.http.address</name>
      <value>http://localhost:50030</value>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.jobhistory.location</name>
      <value>/home/osboxes/hadoop/logs/jobhistory</value>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
      <value>http://localhost:10020</value>
  </property>

  <property>
     <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.intermediate-done-dir</name>
     <value>/home/osboxes/hadoop/mr-history/temp</value>
  </property>

  <property>
     <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.done-dir</name>
     <value>/home/osboxes/hadoop/mr-history/done</value>
  </property>

  <property>
     <name>mapreduce.cluster.local.dir</name>
     <value>/home/osboxes/hadoop/dfs/local</value>
  </property>

  <property>
     <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.system.dir</name>
     <value>/home/osboxes/hadoop/dfs/system</value>
  </property>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
  <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
      <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
      <description> Execution Framework </description>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
      <value>1024</value>
  </property>
```

**EDITED 30-Oct-2015**

**core-site.xml**

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hadoop.hosts</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hadoop.groups</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
```

Comment: AFAIK the job properties that meddle with RAM are `mapreduce.map.memory.mb` plus `mapreduce.map.java.opts` (that one may contain -X reqs), `mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb` plus `mapreduce.reduce.java.opts`, `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb` plus `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts` -- and optionally `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` / `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` if you have Fair or Capacity scheduler enabled.

Comment: Then `hive.tez.container.size` plus `hive.tez.java.opts`, `tez.am.resource.memory.mb` plus `tez.am.java.opts` when using Hive and/or Tez.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter - I'm aware of the properties surrounding the memory allocation, but I am not able to get a perfect working number for these, so that the job runs fine without any error. If you can point me to the solution then that would be helpful instead of me researching which is not what this platform is about.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like User group permissions issue Try running it as Oozie USER.

Comment: I don't think so, else it would have said something about "Authentication failure" in the logs, which I don't find anywhere. Though I am adding an edit for the core-site .xml just in case.